# How to correctly do unit testing with this configuration

Tags: unit-testing

I've got a WPF solution that interacts with Webservices in order to retrieve data.
My application is divided in modules for manteinability and there's a 1:1 correnspondency between WPF modules and Web service's part. I use ServiceStack as layer to perform web service call and my WPF modules use repository pattern to isolate calls.

WPF assemblies are compiled with FW 4.0 (since it has to bee used on XP also) meanwhile Web are FW 4.5.2

I was wondering what's the best solution to debug such repositories without the need to have a Web server configured for this purpose. In my mind if I've the possibility to run both on 4.5.2 I would set up a self-hosted webservice that loads the web module and performs call without having the need to have a web server configured for that... any suggestion/proposal on that?